# Displaying data from MySQL table in HTML table as it correlates to date values

Tags: php, mysql

Basically I am creating a table to display work shifts in a table from a MySQL table, how would I go about displaying the correct shift in each  as it correlates to the week and day?

For example, my table would look like

```
Date    Monday        Tuesday        Wednesday        Thursday        Friday        Saturday        Sunday
08/12   < ^staffname  < ^staffname   < ^staffname     < ^staffname    < ^staffname  < ^staffname    < ^staffname
15/12   < ^staffname  < ^staffname   < ^staffname     < ^staffname    < ^staffname  < ^staffname    < ^staffname
22/12   < ^staffname  < ^staffname   < ^staffname     < ^staffname    < ^staffname  < ^staffname    < ^staffname
29/12   < ^staffname  < ^staffname   < ^staffname     < ^staffname    < ^staffname  < ^staffname    < ^staffname
```

I hope my example makes sense... I'm new to php/mysql and this is frying my brain.

The way I understand it is that I would need to use some sort of loop to recognise when there is data and then output this result in the cell? And a statement that matches the cell to the weekdate and day? I don't know if I'm on the right track there...

Not even sure if my table design is correct...

```
CREATE TABLE workSchedule (
idno int NOT NULL,
surname VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
weekDate DATE,
DayDate DATE
```

);

the idno and surname would be valued from another table.

Thanks.

edit:
The other table I have is called nurses

```
CREATE TABLE nurses (
surname varchar(20) not null,
forename varchar(20) not null,
password varchar(20) not null,
nurseslevel varchar(10) not null,
login1 varchar(40) not null,
login2 varchar(40) not null,
idno int primary key
```

);

This table stores the staff details, when the staff member is logged in and they see the calendar and select a shift I was going to insert their idno and surname in to the workSchedule table.

As of right now the only PHP code I have for the table gets the individual values from the workSchedule table,

```
<table border="1px solid black" cellpadding="0px" cellspacing="0px" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Date</th>
                <th>Monday</th>
                <th>Tuesday</th>
                <th>Wednesday</th>
                <th>Thursday</th>
                <th>Friday</th>
                <th>Saturday</th>
                <th>Sunday</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <?php

                while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
                    echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<td>" . $row[1] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $row['surname'] . "</td>";
                    echo "</tr>";
                }
            ?>

        </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: There isn't enough to go on here. We need to see the table schema for each table in question. We'll also need to see the existing php code that's being used to draw them, working or not.

Comment: Since `nurses` is your primary table you should have an autoincrement on that and a primary key, such as `id` that can be used to cross reference against `idno` that is in your workSchedule table. This will help simplify things. In reality though, I think you should [check out this article](http://www.arachnoid.com/MySQL/relational_databases.html) as it will help explain Relational Databases in a simple and straight forward way and would be more beneficial than us creating code to show you.

Comment: Ok thanks for the link @Ohgodwhy that'll help me with my MySQL can you offer any help for my lack of PHP knowledge regarding displaying the data from the tables?